# SVG image style/color change as per external data source

Tags: css, angularjs, svg

I am a beginner in svg and angular js.
I have a collection of svg images in my html page as a group.Among them, I have an SVG circle as follows:

```html
<div> 
<svg>
<g>
....
<circle id="myCircle" cx="100" cy="40" r="5" style="stroke:#909090;stroke-width:1px;fill:#ff0000;" />
..
</g>
</svg>
  </div>
```

I need to change the color of circle from red to blue as per the input from an external data source using angular js. How can i do it ? I tried to insert a div tag inside svg and applied ng-if but div tag inside svg is not working. I can't put the condition in common div as it may affect other SVG elements. How can I do it? Please help...
Thanks in advance :)

Well, I have found an answer for this problem...
I deleted the div tag and modified the code as follows:

```html
<circle ng-if="Externaldata == value" cx="100" cy="40" r="5" stroke="blue" stroke-width="5" fill="blue" />
```

Comment: You can do it by binding the fill attribute of your circle with your angular controller

Answer (score 0):

use `ngStyle`:

```
//color here is a variable which is set in your controller and holds the color value
<svg ng-style="{'fill': color}">
</svg>
```

And in your controller, set `$scope.color` to whatever color based on your external input source. Also, set it to a default value:

```
$scope.color = "#ff0000";
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply... I tried it out but  if  I follow this way, as I use single SVG tag for all elements and thus if I give style in common it will be applied to each and every element I write inside.... But my requirement is style specific to an element... I have found a solution to the problem which is attached to the question. Once again thank you so much for the response...

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have found an answer for this problem...
I deleted the div tag and modified the code as follows:

```html
<circle ng-if="Externaldata == value" cx="100" cy="40" r="5" stroke="blue" stroke-width="5" fill="blue" />
```